# SAML federated authentication

Tags: federated-authentication

I have been running into a problem with `Sitecore federated authentication`, and am looking for help. We have even been working with Sitecore, but not getting the help we need.

We have `Sitecore 9.0 171002` using federated authentication with the identity server disabled.  We are using Ping for the identity provider.

We are using the Sustainsys package for `SAML authentication`, with the `Kentor.OwinCookieServer` package and the Sitecore `DefaultCookieAuthenticationOptions`. I have implemented the same code for another client that uses Okta for the IDP and had it working without much grief.

Our issue is that we are successfully authenticating with Ping, and successfully signing on using the SigninManager. After signing in, it goes to the Launchpad.. and then redirected right back to the sign-in form.  I know there is something missing in the configuration or code, but after hours of looking into it, I have not yet determined what it is.

The configuration looks like this.  At this point my head is bleeding from banging it against the wall, looking for a paramedic.

```
<federatedAuthentication type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" patch:source="Authentication.config">
  <!--   List of all the shared transformations -->
  <sharedTransformations hint="list:AddSharedClaimsTransformation">
    <!--  Adds an 'idp claim' type to the identity.  -->
    <transformation name="set idp claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SetIdpClaimTransform, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"/>
    <!--
Removes the specified claims from the identity to minimize cookie size. 
-->
    <transformation name="sanitize claims" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.RemoveClaims, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <claimTypes hint="list"/>
    </transformation>
    <!--
If external authentication is configured with "TokenValidationParameters = {SaveSigninToken = true}", this saves the value from "claimsIdentity.BootstrapContext" to the "id_token" claim. 
-->
    <transformation name="set id_token claim" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.SaveIdTokenInClaim, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"/>
  </sharedTransformations>
  <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
    <maps hint="list"/>
  </propertyInitializer>
  <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider" patch:source="Authentication.config">
    <identityProvider id="saml2" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
      <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
      <param type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" desc="domainManager" resolve="true"/>
      <caption>Single Sign On</caption>
      <domain>sitecore</domain>
      <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
        <transformation type="XXXXXXXX.IdentityClaimTransformation,XXXXXXXX.Foundation"/>
      </transformations>
    </identityProvider>
  </identityProviders>
  <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites" patch:source="Authentication.config">
    <mapEntry name="web site" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication" resolve="true">
      <sites hint="list">
        <site>shell</site>
        <site>login</site>
        <site>admin</site>
        <site>service</site>
        <site>modules_shell</site>
        <site>modules_website</site>
        <site>website</site>
        <site>scheduler</site>
        <site>system</site>
        <site>publisher</site>
      </sites>
      <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
        <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='saml2']"/>
      </identityProviders>
      <externalUserBuilder type="XXXXXXXX.Services.PingUserBuilder,XXXXXXXX.Foundation"/>
    </mapEntry>
  </identityProvidersPerSites>
</federatedAuthentication>
```

Comment: Please check network trace from chrome dev tools , what happens after the redirection to sitecore launchpad , is there any http error or just a 302 POST

Comment: Just a 302 POST

Comment: You may have to debug the custom codes for userbuilder and transformation to check if anywhere you are sending Response.Redirect